# tf.keras model very low accuracy and zero loss

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

```
from keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
from keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences

tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words = 5408)
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(training_sentences)

word_index = tokenizer.word_index

vocab_size = len(tokenizer.word_index)

training_sequences = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(training_sentences)
training_padded = pad_sequences(training_sequences, padding='post', truncating='post', maxlen = 30)

testing_sequences = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(testing_sentences)
testing_padded = pad_sequences(testing_sequences, padding='post', truncating='post', maxlen = 30)


model = tf.keras.Sequential([
                             tf.keras.layers.Embedding(vocab_size, 1400),
                             tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
                             tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling1D(),
                             tf.keras.layers.Dense(34, activation='softmax'),
                             tf.keras.layers.Dense(50, activation='relu'),
                             tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
])
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='rmsprop',metrics=['accuracy'])

history = model.fit(training_padded, training_labels, epochs = 5, 
                    validation_data=(testing_padded, testing_labels), verbose=2)
```

```
Epoch 1/5
44/44 - 4s - loss: 0.0000e+00 - accuracy: 0.0579 - val_loss: 0.0000e+00 - val_accuracy: 0.0379 - 4s/epoch - 97ms/step
Epoch 2/5
44/44 - 3s - loss: 0.0000e+00 - accuracy: 0.0579 - val_loss: 0.0000e+00 - val_accuracy: 0.0379 - 3s/epoch - 77ms/step
Epoch 3/5
44/44 - 3s - loss: 0.0000e+00 - accuracy: 0.0579 - val_loss: 0.0000e+00 - val_accuracy: 0.0379 - 3s/epoch - 69ms/step
Epoch 4/5
44/44 - 3s - loss: 0.0000e+00 - accuracy: 0.0579 - val_loss: 0.0000e+00 - val_accuracy: 0.0379 - 3s/epoch - 69ms/step
Epoch 5/5
44/44 - 3s - loss: 0.0000e+00 - accuracy: 0.0579 - val_loss: 0.0000e+00 - val_accuracy: 0.0379 - 3s/epoch - 75ms/step
```

My dataset consists of texts with 17 classes. I have preprocessed it by doing stop word removal, punctuation removal, lowercasing. Is the extremely low accuracy due to a problem in the code?

Comment: If you have 17 classes, why do you have a single output neuron with a sigmoid activation?

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy Was following another tutorial where the dataset had a couple of labels. Is sigmoid not be used at all or should I change its configurations?

Comment: This model is doing binary classification, not 17-class classification, that is why it does not work.

Comment: @Dr. Snoopy what I could understand was that softmax could be used for multiple classes. I am a bit lost on where and how to specify the 17-class classification

Comment: @EnesErdemErdogan you can replace `tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')` with `tf.keras.layers.Dense(17, activation='softmax')`